# long distance measuring modules - experiences: ME007-ULS V1

Tags: sensor

I am searching for a cheap non contact long distance (1 to more than 10 metres) measurement sensor with an accuracy <= 1cm. I'm already using the hc-sr04 ultrasonic in combination with the dht22 temperature sensor. It has a range of around 7m.

Would it be possible to enlarge the range by increasing the electrical current?

Has anyone any experiences with the ME007-ULS V1 ultrasonic sensor [<sup>EBay link</sup>](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ME007-ULS-V1-Waterproof-Ultrasonic-Sensor-Module-Measuring-Range-25cm-8m-/381346466395)?

The data sheet says that it can take a distance up to 9 m; principally it should be connectible to the RPi the same way as the hc-sr04, further more a temperature sensor is included and it is waterproof.

Is there somebody with experience with that or other long distance measuring devices?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think your <1cm accuracy requirement is going to be difficult at that range, and with a budget smaller than the GDP of Switzerland. If you could relax that a little then I LIDAR is more plausible than ultrasonics: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/13680 .